# How can you randomly open an imageView by clicking on another imageview?

Tags: java, android, random, imageview

I want to program an Android game where there are different ImageViews in the View. By clicking on a button, different pictures should randomly be assigned to the Images on the view.

After that you Click on one of the Images in the view and the randomly assigned Image should Open.

I want to program all of this with the visibilities but I also need a random instruction with all the images. But you can't put images in an array, so how can I solve this program?

I know it's very hard to understate my problem, but still I'll be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Put an identifier of the image into the array e.g. filename.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are local, just grab the resource IDs and out them into an array or list, and randomly select from there.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not really into this, so: where can i find the resource IDs and do you mean the IDs of the ImageViews that should randomly appear by clicking on the local Images ?